# RegEX to find IN (x, x) and replace X, X with 2 values after

Tags: c#, regex

Hey all I am trying to find a REGEX that can take the next 2 values *after* the IN (x, x) and grab those values.

The example:

```
something IN (x, x) Value1 Value2 Bobshelf ID
```

The Regex would be able to find both values within the string like:

> Value1
>   Value2

Code I currently have tried:

```
_SelectQuery = _SelectQuery.replace(/(^\s*,)|(,\s*$)/g, '');
var get2Values = _SelectQuery.(/IN \(x, x\) (\S*) (\S*)/g, '');
_SelectQuery += " IN (" + get2Values + ") ";
```

Comment: If you are trying, could you share to see what exactly you are doing?

Comment: Which characters are valid in value1 and value2?

Answer (score 1):

`IN \(x, x\) (\S*) (\S*)` and on `$1` and `$2` are desired values.

Comment: What if there is `SIN(y,z) Value1 Value2`?

Comment: `IN( )?\(\S\,( )?\S\) (\S*) (\S*)` matches your question (and values are on `$3` and `$4`), but that's not original one.

Comment: Thanks for the help there, maciek!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
.* ?IN \(x, x\) +([^ ]+) +([^ ]+)
```

Updated to allow text to be set in front of the `IN (x, x)` part.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/WZiS8L0211opT0o5)

Comment: What if there is `MIN(y,z) Value1 Value2`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew As written, I don't feel the question allows this as an input. I can adjust the regex if it turns out it *should* be a match. =)